# Remove parent item in a sub category list (wp_list_categories)

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-list-categories

**UPDATE:
Nevermind, stupid error: it wasn't actually showing the parent title, it was a sub category with the same name.**

I have the following list to display the child categories of the current category and I'd like to remove or hide the parent item, showing only the children. Is it possible without writing a function in functions.php?

HTML:

```
<div class="tabs">  
    <ul>
        <?php $this_cat = (get_query_var('cat')) ? get_query_var('cat') : 1; ?>
        <?php $this_category = get_category($this_cat);
        if ( $this_category->parent ) { $this_cat = $this_category->parent; } ?>
        <?php wp_list_categories('child_of=' . $this_cat . '&title_li='); ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

RESULT:

"issue of the year" is the parent which I want to remove

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, stupid error: it wasn't actually showing the parent title, it was a sub category with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

If you have id of category parent ,you can use [get_term_children](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_children)

Ex:

```
$chlidrenCategories = get_term_children( categoryParentId ,'Category');
```

Comment: that wouldn't work because it's a general list that goes into every page, so I need it to fetch its current category